Sending message successfully from background.js to content.js but code in content.js not running
I am trying to write my first Chrome extension and I require the background.js file to listen for reloads on the Netflix website and run a script that interacts with the DOM in content.js.
I am unable to set up the connection between the two files so I have commented everything out and I am trying to make only a console.log run in my content.js file but cannot to do that either.
content.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action === "hello") {
        console.log("Hello from content script");
        sendResponse({ status: "done" });
    }
});

background.js:
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === "complete" && tab.url && tab.url.includes("netflix.com/watch/")) {
        console.log("Netflix watch page loaded in tab", tabId);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: "hello" }, () => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.error("Sending message failed:", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Message sent to content script successfully");
            }
        });
    }
});

manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "MyTudum",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "templates/popup.html",
        "default_icon": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "scripts/content.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "https://*/*",
                "http://*/*"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/logo.png",
        "32": "images/logo.png",
        "48": "images/logo.png",
        "128": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.netflix.com/*"
    ]
}

Directory strucutre for reference:
directory structure image
The output I get is:
Netflix watch page loaded in tab 317397541
Message sent to content script successfully

There is no error. Shouldn't I also be getting the output files from content.js?
I am trying to fix this code so that the output also has the console.log() lines from content.js in the console, so that I can understand how to get the function in content.js to run properly.

The sendMessage code is correct which is confirmed by console log, so the problem may be that the site clears the console or you have a filter in devtools console toolbar.
Don't rely on console. Add a breakpoint in devtools at if (request.action === "hello") { and generally prefer using the interactive debugger in devtools because it allows you to inspect the state of DOM and other variables at the exact moment e.g. when the message is received. The breakpoints can also be non-interactive and just print something. The advantage is that you don't need to reload the extension in order to trace the execution flow in a different part of the code.
Other problems:

Don't declare content_scripts for all sites in matches if you only need one (netflix).

Re-inject content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome.

Avoid chrome.tabs.onUpdated as it wakes up the background script for every navigation in every tab, which may happen hundreds of times a day.
A better solution is to register a targeted listener for the URLs that you're interested in:
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(info => {
  if (!info.frameId) chrome.tabs.sendMessage(info.tabId, 'nav');
}, { url: [{hostSuffix: '.netflix.com'}] });

...and add "webNavigation" to "permissions" in manifest.json.

Prefer detecting navigation without using the background script right in the content script:
navigation.onnavigatesuccess = e => {
  console.log(location.href);
};

In Firefox it's not yet supported, so you can use MutationObserver, example.


